# Can I send string to IME (Windows) to get translation?

Tags: windows, internationalization, ime

For example (I'm using Korean IME btw) can I get 태우다 from sending "xodnek" (as a string)?

If that isn't possible, can I get 태우다 from it's individual characters ㅌㅐㅇㅜㄷㅏ (which is from the keys "xodnek").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET, the following will work:

```
var s = "ㅌㅐㅇㅜㄷㅏ";
s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
// s now contains "태우다"
```

In native Win32, the corresponding call is [NormalizeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319093%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
wchar_t *input = L"ㅌㅐㅇㅜㄷㅏ";
wchar_t output[100];
NormalizeString(NormalizationKC, input, -1, output, 100);
```

NormalizeString is only available in Windows Vista+. You need the "[Microsoft Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) Mitigation APIs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AD6158D7-DDBA-416A-9109-07607425A815&displaylang=en)" installed if you want to use it on XP (why it's in the IDN download, I don't understand...)

Note that neither of these methods actually requires use of the IME - they work regardless of whether you've got the Korean IME installed or not.

Comment: Thank you!
Another thing, I'm using Delphi, I can't seem to use the NormalizeString (undeclared identifier error). Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (already downloaded the Api & finished running the setup wizard).

Comment: @Dian: unfortunately, I don't know enough about Delphi to be able to help you with that. I assume there must be some way to call C APIs in DLLs, but I don't know what it is, sorry!

Comment: Oh, okay. I've never used DLLs before, so that's why I don't know, but there is definitely a way to do that.

Thanks again for your answer. It helped heaps.

Comment: I made it work...but I have an issue. I think it's the characters that have 3 keystrokes. 
When I type "ane" I get "무ㄷ" instead of "묻". Is it just me? Is this a bug?